# Error: The underlying secure session has faulted before the reliable session fully completed. The reliable session was faulted

Tags: wcf

Can you please help us on the below issue?

We are getting error message as "The underlying secure session has faulted before the reliable session fully completed. The reliable session was faulted."

I have provided the config settings we are using  and the error message.

```
ERROR  2019-08-06 05:43:48,368 1789797ms ServiceProxy`1         Invoke             - The underlying secure session has faulted before the reliable session fully completed. The reliable session was faulted. 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.WaitQueueReader.Wait(TimeSpan timeout, T& value)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dequeue(TimeSpan timeout, T& value)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.Dequeue(TimeSpan timeout, TDisposable& item)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DuplexChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

We have gone through the below link but none of the solutions provided in the link worked for us. 
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e87b039-6afb-4751-8edb-15699ce305e4/error-message-the-underlying-secure-session-has-faulted-before-the-reliable-session-fully-completed?forum=wcf

We have also enabled both trace logging and failed request tracing, but none of them
 provided any insights on exact issue. Can you please suggest how can we know the cause for the above issue.

Thank You.

```html
CONFIG SETTINGS

 > <behaviors>
 > <serviceBehaviors>
 > <behavior name="svcBehav">
 >         <serviceAuthorization>
 >          <authorizationPolicies>
 >            <add > 
 >policyType="DistributedServices.PanelManagement.Security.AuthPolicy, >DistributedServices.PanelManagement" />
 >           </authorizationPolicies>
  >        </serviceAuthorization>
  >        <persistenceSession />
  >        <customMessageInspector />
  >        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  >       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
   >       <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
  ><serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions = "50"/>
   >     </behavior>
></serviceBehaviors>
></behaviors>
 ><bindings>
 ><customBinding>
  >      <binding name="netTcpCustomBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:59:00" >openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
 >         <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:00" >maxPendingChannels="20" maxRetryCount="20"/>
 >         <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
  >        <binaryMessageEncoding>
   >         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" >maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" >maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
 >         </binaryMessageEncoding>
  >        <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
 >                      portSharingEnabled="true" transferMode="Buffered" >hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10">
 >  <connectionPoolSettings maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="100"/>
></tcpTransport>
 >       </binding>
 ></customBinding>
> </bindings>

 ><services>
  ><service name="DistributedServices.PanelManagement.Services.GridService" >behaviorConfiguration="svcBehav">
 >       <endpoint >address="net.tcp://localhost:865/tcpsvces/services/GridService.svc"
 >     behaviorConfiguration="unitOfWorkBehavior" binding="customBinding" >bindingConfiguration="netTcpCustomBindingConfig"
 >     contract="DistributedServices.PanelManagement.Contracts.IGridService" >/>
 >       <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" >bindingConfiguration="netTcpCustomBindingConfig" >contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     > </service>
 ></services>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 general reasons for this error message.  The first is with readerQuotas.  Usually it is fixed just by increasing MaxStringContentLength (which you seem to have set large enough).  I would increase other values in the readerQuotas to see if the problem goes away.

The second reason for this is if the data is serialized to go across the wire and when the deserialization is attempted the object has no setter defined for the data.  So go through your data definition for your service and make sure you are not missing any setter definitions.  Also if there are fields without setters that should NOT be passed across, make sure they are tagged as not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered a similar problem, which may have something to do with some configurations.
I suggest you try other bindings to create the service so that we could locate the problem, such as nettcpbinding, and configure the readerQuotas section.
Such as,

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
            enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Besides, please check the below document. wish it is useful to you.
https://www.dofactory.com/topic/1339/session-has-faulted-timeout.aspx
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7f4e91d-07e9-4139-a6ea-b203a71a4631/the-underlying-secure-session-has-faulted-before-the-reliable-session-fully-completed-the-reliable
http://girl-programmer.blogspot.com/2013/05/wcf-quotas.html
https://blog.petegoo.com/2008/04/15/wcf-exceptions-and-fault-contracts/
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.